# Functions such that $f(x)=\int f(x) \text{d}x = \frac{\text{d}\left(f(x)\right)}{\text{d}x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, derivatives

Are there functions $f$, aside for $g(x)=0$ with the choice of $c=0$ as arbitrary constant of integration and $h(x)=e^x$ , that satisfies
$$f(x)=\int f(x) \text{d}x = \frac{\text{d}\left(f(x)\right)}{\text{d}x}?$$
And if there are, how to find all of them?
A naive idea is to take derivative and integrate both sides, leading to
$$f(x)=\frac{\text{d}\left(f(x)\right)}{\text{d}x}=\frac{\text{d}^2\left(f(x)\right)}{\text{d}x^2}$$
And
$$f(x)+\tilde{c}=\int f(x) \text{d}x=\int\left(\int f(x) \text{d}x\right)\text{d}x$$
But I don't know if it has sense. Thanks.

Comment: $f(x)=\int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ doesn't make a lot of sense because the indefinite integral is not a function but a set of functions (antiderivatives). It can make sense if you replace $=$ with $\in$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suposse that $f=f'$ and $f$ is defined in an interval, then $(f(x)e^{-x})'=f'(x)e^{-x}-f(x)e^{-x}=f'(x)e^{-x}-f'(x)e^{-x}=0$, so $f(x)e^{-x}=c\Rightarrow f(x)=ce^{x}$ , $c$ is a constant.

Comment: Did you specify that $f$ and $f'$ are defined in an interval because $f'=0 \Rightarrow f=c$ only in an interval (for the mean value theorem)?
Why this argument satisfy the condition $f=f'=\int f$ too? Even if now we have an explicit espression for $f$, if we integrate it we get $ce^x + k$ so there is another constant; maybe we can solve this by imposing $f=f'$ again and find that $k$ must be $0$?
Thanks.

Comment: @Dunkelheit Usually we define ∫f(x)dx:={h(x):h'(x)=f(x)} and if f is defined in an interval and g'=f then for every function h such that h'=f exist a constant c such that g(x)+c=h(x), that´s the meaning of the equality ∫f(x)dx=g(x)+c. So the condition doesn′t make sense because in the left is a function and in the right side is a set of functions.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = \frac{d f}{dx}$, then by [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Ordinary_differential_equations_(ODE)), we can write (provided $f \neq 0$, but since $\frac{df}{dx} = f$, if $f$ is negative at some point, it will be negative everywhere and similarly for positive) $\int f^{-1} df = \int dx$, so $\ln f = x + C$. Thus $f(x) = e^{x+C} = Ae^x$ for some constant $A$. Thus these are all the possibilities.